# Subtract D&A is necessary

Tags: amortization, depreciation, income-statement

I read *Warren Buffett and the interpretation of the financial statements*, but depreciation and amortization thing still confuses me a lot. When I look at the Microsoft's income statement (i.e. https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/MSFT/income-statement), the operation income are obtained by subtracting the R&D and SG&A from the Gross Profit. However, as it is explained in the book, we should subtract D&A as well. Is it fine to subtract the D&A from the cashflow statement from operating expense to get the updated operating expense?

[image]

Interesting video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1eL5Z0Y6mTo

Answer (score 1):

No, you should not subtract it again. It is already included in one of the other line items, most likely Cost of Revenue. Just because it is not broken out into its own separate line item does not mean that it is not included in Net Income somehow.

Comment: How can you be sure it is already included in SG&A or R&D? Because the way they described SG&A and R&D not include the D&A. Can I add something up to verify the exact item considered in the computation of SG&A for instance?\

Comment: I said it was most likely in Cost of Revenues (and thus implicitly subtracted from Gross Profit), not SG&A or R&D. MS does not break it out in the notes on their financial statements, so I searched for "Microsoft depreciation" and saw another site that listed it under Cost of Revenue. I cannot guarantee that it is correct (it's another aggregator like SA) but you can safely assume that it's included in net income _somewhere_. If it matters whether it's in Gross Profit or not, you may have to dig further or make your own assumption.